# 'Content is Not Allowed in Prolog'

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

Code is at the end of the post.
Did some googling and it looks like this error occurs if you have data before your root data tag in your XML file. I've looked at the byte stream that is coming in and it starts with 60 or '<'. So there isn't some weird Byte-Order-Mark or something at the beginning of the file.

What else could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks SO!

```
 XMLReader r = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
 SAXSource source = new SAXSource(new NamespaceFilter(r), new InputSource(is));

 validator.validate(source, null);
```

Comment: Obviously the problem is in `NamespaceFilter` -- it's corrupting the input stream.  Since you haven't provided the source we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: this generally indicates that there is some data before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` declaration; it can also happen if the declared encoding doesn't match the one used to write the document.

Answer (score 0):

The only things allowed outside of root element are XML declaration, comments and processing instructions. So it is possible that document starts correctly but there is some other crap (non-whitespace) before the root element. BOMs could indeed cause this issue too, if parser didn't know how to deal with it, but this is probably not the case here.

You could also consider trying Stax parser such as Woodstox, since while it would probably hit same problem (whatever it is), it should be able to give you bit more information on actual problem -- message you get is too sparse, parser is being lazy; it should at least indicate location (relative to beginning of file).

Answer (score 0):

i've seen this issue when using compression.  the uncompressed stream sometimes gets an extra character.